# Find images on ImageView Click

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have an activity with button whose image keeps on changing. Now on click of the button with particular image at that time should give proper toast. I am using timerTask to change the button image. How can I get different response for clicking different image that appears in the button(here my button is an Image View).

My code is given below

Activity

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public  ImageView ib;
     int[] images=  {R.drawable.alarm,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.music_player,R.drawable.onetouchpanel,R.drawable.recorder};


    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ib=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    int delay = 0; // delay for 0 sec.
    int period = 2000; // repeat every 2 seconds.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(myTask, delay,period);
    ib.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    //ib.measure(Me, heightMeasureSpec)

    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("ayaz","button clicked");

        }
    });
}
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    int i=0;
  public void run() {
      runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             // ERROR
             ib.setImageResource(images[i]);
             i++;
             if(i>images.length-1)
             {
                 i=0;
             }

        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: And what is your Question ?

Comment: @Lucifer how can i get to know  which image was there when i clicked my image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the variable "`i`" from `run()` into the `MainActivity` class.

Also add a `Button` "names" array to the class:

```
private int i;
private final static String[] names = {"alarm", "launcher", "player", "onetouchpanel", "recorder"};
```

Modify your code as follows to display a `Toast` in the `Button.onClick()` function:

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String name = names[i];
        Log.d("ayaz","button clicked: #" + i + ". " + name);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ayaz: button clicked: #" + i + ". " + name,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: P.S. You might want to consider incrementing your counter like this: `i = (i + 1) % images.length;` to make the code more concise - One line to rule them all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a real problem or not, but if there was a timer tick during `onClick`, could it preempt the processing? I'd probably cache the value with `int clicked = i;` at the start of the function.

Comment: @DavidManpearl you answer is exactly what i wanted..plz vote up my question, if u liked it

Comment: @DavidManpearl how can i do the same thing using alarmManager instead of using TimerTask

Answer (score 0):

You can set proper text into view tag.

Put 
`ib.setTag("Text to be displayed");`
after `ib.setImageResource(images[i]);` and then display a toast with text inside an onClick

`Toast.makeText(context, (String)v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`